# Electron ejecting from surface while photoelectric effect

Tags: photons, electrons, atomic-physics

[image: ci]

Even after increasing the frequency why does the the ratio of
Number of electron ejecting/number of capable photons to take out the electron remains constant?
Check the image attached.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Photoelectric effect and work function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/253786/photoelectric-effect-and-work-function)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the frequency of light i.e the energy does not change the number of electrons release (as long the energy of the photons is above the work function). If you have the same number of photons, then only that many of electrons will be released. If you change only the frequency, only the kinetic energy of the electrons released will increase (because of the higher energy of the photons). To increase the number of electrons ejected, you must increase the number of photons i.e the intensity of the light. PS: This was one of the phenomena which led to the acceptance of light being made up of particles).